# Can not retrieve cookie-based TempData after Google authentication with account selection

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-2.0

Using ASP.NET Core 1.1, I set up cookie-based `TempData`.  Within this key/value store,  I stored temporary data prior to logging in to an external login provider (Google) which I retrieved in the callback of the authentication request.

This worked and I do not recall any problems with this.

I now upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2.0. One of the changes made is cookie-based `TempData` is now configured by default. Indeed, when removing the configuration the data stored temporarily when logging in with Google Authentication can still be retrieved.

However, I now noticed this fails when multiple Google accounts are configured in Google Chrome and the user needs to make a selection which one to log in with. When only one account is configured no interaction is needed,  the user is logged in automatically, and `TempData` can be retrieved.

Debugging this, I noticed that the cookie is written (can see it in Chrome settings) and is even still there when the authentication callback is called. Regardless, `TempData` is empty when queried. An exception occurs since the expected key can't be found, and only subsequently the cookie is no longer visible in Chrome settings. Interestingly, only the `TempData` cookie is removed. Even more interesting, **this problem does not occur on Microsoft Edge**!

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?  I am not certain whether or not this problem occurred in ASP.NET 1.0. Possibly I simply did not run into it.

Answer (score 1):

This [seems to be a bug, or at least unexpected behavior,](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7190) in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

As [Tratcher pointed out in the GitHub issue I created,](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7190#issuecomment-355480978) this is related to the [newly introduced `SameSite` option for cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite).

> SameSite prevents the browser from sending this cookie along with
>   cross-site requests.

ASP.NET MVC's [`CookieTempDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.cookietempdataprovideroptions.cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_CookieTempDataProviderOptions_Cookie) defaults to `SameSiteMode.Strict`, which [the Open Web Application Security Project documents as:](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite)

> The strict value will prevent the cookie from being sent by the
>   browser to the target site in all cross-site browsing context, even
>   when following a regular link.

The solution therefore is to set this to `SameSiteMode.Lax`, which is documented as:

> The default lax value provides a reasonable balance between security
>   and usability for websites that want to maintain user's logged-in
>   session after the user arrives from an external link. In the above
>   GitHub scenario, the session cookie would be allowed when following a
>   regular link from an external website while blocking it in CSRF-prone
>   request methods (e.g. POST).

This is possible by adding the following code to `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
// Ensure TempData cookies do not get cleared when using external Google Authentication.
services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>( options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax; // By default this is set to 'Strict'.
} );
```

The reason it works for Microsoft Edge is because (at the time of writing) Edge does not yet support `SameSite`.